# PHP computed associative array keys?

Tags: php, key, associative-array, computed-properties

I would like to create an associative array with computed keys, like e.g:

```
    if ($arr[$mid]["something"] == $x) {
        $foundPlaces = Array(
            `$computedKey` => $arr[$mid]["some_other"];
        )
        print_r($foundPlaces);
        return $foundPlaces; 
    }
```

I use binSearch to search for an array Values based on some key, if that key exists, I would like to create an associative array with the key as computed Values (not as a string) and assign the corresponding found value for that key with it and return the array...

the above syntax doesn't work, I know its possible in Javascript with brackets and [key] or so, but no idea how that works in php?

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Variables can be used as array keys.

Comment: ok I simple used 'sometring' => key, and 'otherstring' => value and returned the array... I thought something like computed fields on an object like in Javascript would be possible..

Answer (score 1):

You was very close, I think it will help you:

```
    if ($arr[$mid]["something"] == $x) {
        // $computedKey = "result_of_computing"; // can be like this
        // $computedKey = 18; // or like this
        $foundPlaces = [
            $computedKey => $arr[$mid]["some_other"];
        ]
        print_r($foundPlaces);
        return $foundPlaces; 
    }
```